# Scroll down is not working report

Tags: reporting, joined-reports

I had an issue with the salesforce report , scroll down is not working. When selecting a date field to use in a report filter, clicking on the scrollbar to scroll down in the field list will immediately close the dialog, preventing selections.
[image]

I cannot scroll after fiscal quarter.it is really frustrating.please provide anyone the solution for this?

Comment: I have tested this behavior in my org- Clicking the scroll bar makes the window disappear.  I don't think we can navigate to the"sort by" option from the Keyboard keys. You can use the mouse scroll to navigate as a workaround.

Comment: Can you please log a case with Salesforce support and share the case number here? It seems to be a UI bug that needs further investigation.  Regards - Salesforce Support

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing the comments:

Salesforce R&D team has been able to reproduce this reported issue that in Reports builder, by clicking on the scrollbar in "Group Date By", the drop-down menu gets closed. If using a laptop touchpad, this can be seen.

The issue has been confirmed as a UI bug and we have filed a new investigation numbered #W-8388291 that you can use as a reference. (I have followed up for a known issue to be created and will update this thread as I have more inputs)

This behaviour has been seen on multiple browsers- Google Chrome, Safari, Firefox. The workaround is to use the mouse scroll bar.